# Subset a dataframe in two dataframes by values in two columns of another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes.
 df1 looks like (or the column of df1 i am interested in):

```
position
2
6
12
18
25
31
```

and df2 looks like:

```
start   end
2       17
24      29
```

I want to keep the positions in df1 that only fall between (<= or >=) the start and end coordinates of df2, so that df1 looks like this after filtering:

```
position
2
6
12
25
```

Then I want to keep the filtered out "leftover" values of df1 in another dataframe, let's call it df4.

df4 would look like:

```
position
18
31
```

I can do this the perl way using a for loop (coming from perl and currently learning R) but I am pretty sure I can somehow use filter or some other dplyr or base R combination of functions to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Added df4 calculation as my question was marked as duplicate and this is sth not found in the other similar threads. This is something I am interested in doing to make my code faster!

Comment: you mean 18, 31 for df4

Comment: Yes, corrected this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `full_join` these two data frames and then filter for the rows within the `start` and `end` column. The `Flag` column in the example is just for the join. Finally, we can use `distinct` to remove duplicated rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Flag = 1) %>%
  full_join(df2 %>% mutate(Flag = 1), by = "Flag") %>%
  filter(position >= start, position <= end) %>%
  distinct(position)
df3
#   position
# 1        3
# 2        6
# 3       12
# 4       25
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "position
3
                  6
                  12
                  18
                  25
                  31", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "start   end
2       17
24      29",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hello www, this an easy for me to understand dplyr solution! I am more familiar with dplyr than base r, so thanx for the great response! Also, this answer provides back a dataframe as I asked for! Is there a way to keep what is filtered out in a df4 without having to repeat this code? (See question EDIT)

Comment: I found that out I think. I could just use:df4<-anti_join(df1, df3, by="position")!

Answer (score 3):

Single line, simple base solution:

```
df1[df1$position %in% unlist(apply(df2,1,function(x) x["start"]:x["end"])),]
```

The apply simply generates a vector of all the cases that fall between starts and ends.

Comment: After a quick check, this seems to be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(i, j) 
  df1[df1$position > i & df1$position < j, , drop = FALSE], 
      df2$start, df2$end))
#    position
#1        3
#2        6
#3       12
#5       25
```

---

Or using `fuzzy_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('position' = 'start', 'position' = 'end'), 
        match_fun = list(`>`, `<`)) %>%
    select(position)
#  position
#1        3
#2        6
#3       12
#4       25
```

---

Or use a non-equi join from `data.table`

```
setDT(df2)[df1, on = .(start < position, end > position), .(position), nomatch = 0]
#   position
#1:        3
#2:        6
#3:       12
#4:       25
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(position = c(3L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 25L, 31L)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(start = c(2L, 24L), end = c(17L, 29L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

`base R` solution (no packages needed)

```
keepRows<-
sapply(df1$position, function(x_o) {
    any(apply(df2, 1, function(x) {x_o => x[1] & x_o <= x[2]}))
})

df1[keepRows,, drop = FALSE]
```

Result:

```
#  position
#1        3
#2        6
#3       12
#5       25
```

---

Please note:

- This is basically a double loop, I don't know how else to solve this with `base::`.
- Should the border values be included? You are very vague with "between". Currently, I don't include them. You can change that using `<=, >=`.

---

To get the "leftover" use negation:

```
df1[!keepRows,, drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Made my question more clear upon your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take that starts with df2 (I don't say this is wiser than Andre's approach):

```
subset(df1, apply(apply(df2, 1, function (x) {dplyr::between(df1$position, x["start"], x["end"])}), 1, any))
```

You should probably run some benchmarks on the proposed approaches before making a decision.

Comment: @AndreElrico Something like DT sometimes has to convert the data. This doesn't make it the ideal solution for all kind of problems. It's okay if the data already is a data.table though.

Comment: @AndreElrico Since I don't use `data.table` the function I use actually is from `dplyr`. Thanks for the hint though. I forgot it isn't in base.